# Should Mac menu items be title case?

Tags: macos, menu-bar, formatting

> Should Mac menu items be title case? "New from Clipboard" vs "New From
>   Clipboard"?

Gus Mueller asked this [question on twitter](https://twitter.com/ccgus/status/636034406126239744) and I am curious as well. If it is title case does it follow a particular set of rules such as the Chicago Manual of Style or [Gruber's script](http://daringfireball.net/2008/05/title_case)? This would be especially good to know when writing scripts to activate menu options which are case sensitive IIRC.

Comment: More like song titles than true title case ;-) of, from, to etc always seem to be lower case, more significant words in title case. [Except 'as' which is Title in Save As.. but lower in Export as PDF.]  idk if there's a rule book, though.

Comment: IMO The menus as cased are just as they should be.

Comment: https://twitter.com/boredzo/status/636063435931803648

Answer (score 2):

With regard to that specific example, it's "New from Clipboard", as shown in the Preview.app File menu.

A cursory glance through some first-party menus shows that every word begins with a capital except articles, conjunctions and prepositions. There's nothing in the [Menu Bar Menus section of the Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/MenuBarMenus.html) talking about the capitalisation.

Comment: It looks like it is not as hard and fast as that (every word begins with a capital except articles, conjunctions and prepositions) as @tetsujin points out.